# UICollectionView: Get cell at screen position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView that I have populated using JSON.  It is a coverflow style layout with movie posters.

I was wondering if there was a way for me to display the title property of a cell at a certain point on the screen so that when i scroll horizontally, the title of the very center visible cell is displayed.

I have tried using indexPathForItemAtPoint, but the point seems to scroll with the collection view, always displaying the same index.

**EDIT:** adding code:

```
UIView *test = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, self.view.frame.size.width+180, 390)];
test.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
superView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];


PerspectiveFlowLayout *layout = [[PerspectiveFlowLayout alloc]init];
self.boxes.bounces = NO;

BoxView *boxes = [[BoxView alloc] initWithFrame:test.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];


[test addSubview:boxes];
[superView addSubview: test];
NSIndexPath *path = [self.boxes indexPathForItemAtPoint:[self.boxes convertPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0) toView:[self.boxes superview]]];

Cell *atpoint = [self.boxes cellForItemAtIndexPath:path];


NSLog(@"%@", atpoint.model.name);
```

Thank you so much for your help,
Logan

Comment: Can you paste a code you are using for that ? indexPathForItemAtPoint should solve your problem, maybe you are using wrong Point coordinates from subview. Are you using convertPoint at any place ?

Comment: i have my boxes UICollectionView as a subview of a UIView and about halfway down the page.  It scrolls horizontally.  I did:         

NSIndexPath *path = [self.boxes indexPathForItemAtPoint: CGPointMake(100.0, 300.0)];

Comment: that will indeed return the first poster, but then when i scroll, it continues to return the first poster every time it is called.

Comment: If you can paste some code it will be helpful. I think you should be using something like: [self.boxes convertPoint:self.boxes.center toView:[self.boxes superview]]. But I need some code to make it more accurate.

Comment: I added that in, and it seems to be having the same behavior.  I posted the code above.

Comment: a coworker suggested possible setting up a hidden view and comparing frames, would that be a better option?

Answer (score 1):

Try swapping the items round when you do the convert point, so you are going from the superview to the collection view:

```
NSIndexPath *path = [self.boxes indexPathForItemAtPoint:[[self.boxes superview] convertPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0) toView:self.boxes]];
```